# Drawing an image using WebGL

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl

Please could anyone explain how to draw an image on a WebGL canvas? At the moment, on a regular '2d' canvas, I'm using this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');

img.onload = function() {
    cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64var;
```

With WebGL it seems you have to use textures, etc. Can anyone explain how I would adapt this code for WebGL? Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 25):

If it was up to me I'd do it with a unit quad and a matrix like this

Given these shaders

vertex shader

```
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform mat3 u_matrix;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_Position = vec4(u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1), 1);

   // because we're using a unit quad we can just use
   // the same data for our texcoords.
   v_texCoord = a_position;  
}
```

fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
</script>
```

I'd create a unit quad and then fill out a 3x3 matrix to translate, rotate, and scale it where I needed it to be

```
  var dstX = 20;
  var dstY = 30;
  var dstWidth = 64;
  var dstHeight = 64;

  // convert dst pixel coords to clipspace coords      
  var clipX = dstX / gl.canvas.width  *  2 - 1;
  var clipY = dstY / gl.canvas.height * -2 + 1;
  var clipWidth = dstWidth  / gl.canvas.width  *  2;
  var clipHeight = dstHeight / gl.canvas.height * -2;

  // build a matrix that will stretch our
  // unit quad to our desired size and location
  gl.uniformMatrix3fv(u_matrixLoc, false, [
      clipWidth, 0, 0,
      0, clipHeight, 0,
      clipX, clipY, 1,
    ]);
```

```js
"use strict";

window.onload = main;

function main() {
  var image = new Image();
  // using a dataURL because stackoverflow
  image.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";  // MUST BE SAME DOMAIN!!!
  image.onload = function() {
    render(image);
  }
}

function render(image) {
  // Get A WebGL context
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position"); 
  
  // look up uniform locations
  var u_imageLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
  var u_matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  // Upload the image into the texture.
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

  var dstX = 20;
  var dstY = 30;
  var dstWidth = 64;
  var dstHeight = 64;

  // convert dst pixel coords to clipspace coords      
  var clipX = dstX / gl.canvas.width  *  2 - 1;
  var clipY = dstY / gl.canvas.height * -2 + 1;
  var clipWidth = dstWidth  / gl.canvas.width  *  2;
  var clipHeight = dstHeight / gl.canvas.height * -2;

  // build a matrix that will stretch our
  // unit quad to our desired size and location
  gl.uniformMatrix3fv(u_matrixLoc, false, [
      clipWidth, 0, 0,
      0, clipHeight, 0,
      clipX, clipY, 1,
    ]);

  // Draw the rectangle.
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

```css
canvas { 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>  
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform mat3 u_matrix;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {

   gl_Position = vec4(u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1), 1);
   v_texCoord = a_position;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
</script>
```

[Here's some articles that will explain the the matrix math](http://webglfundamentals.org/)

Comment: Can I ask you what kind of script is this -> <script src="//webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>? I would love to draw images as well as you do but this scrip is adding some text to pages. Is it possible to run this code just with webgl library without your script?

Comment: [See this article](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html). Adding that code to the example would just clutter the example so I never add it I just link to it

Answer (score 11):

Here is a self-contained script that does what you want, if that helps. All you need to provide is image.jpg.

```
<canvas id="cvs" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
<script>
    var img, tex, vloc, tloc, vertexBuff, texBuff;

    var cvs3d = document.getElementById('cvs');
    var ctx3d = cvs3d.getContext('experimental-webgl');
    var uLoc;

    // create shaders
    var vertexShaderSrc = 
    "attribute vec2 aVertex;" +
    "attribute vec2 aUV;" + 
    "varying vec2 vTex;" +
    "uniform vec2 pos;" +
    "void main(void) {" +
    "  gl_Position = vec4(aVertex + pos, 0.0, 1.0);" +
    "  vTex = aUV;" +
    "}";

    var fragmentShaderSrc =
    "precision highp float;" +
    "varying vec2 vTex;" +
    "uniform sampler2D sampler0;" +
    "void main(void){" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler0, vTex);"+
    "}";

    var vertShaderObj = ctx3d.createShader(ctx3d.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragShaderObj = ctx3d.createShader(ctx3d.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    ctx3d.shaderSource(vertShaderObj, vertexShaderSrc);
    ctx3d.shaderSource(fragShaderObj, fragmentShaderSrc);
    ctx3d.compileShader(vertShaderObj);
    ctx3d.compileShader(fragShaderObj);

    var progObj = ctx3d.createProgram();
    ctx3d.attachShader(progObj, vertShaderObj);
    ctx3d.attachShader(progObj, fragShaderObj);

    ctx3d.linkProgram(progObj);
    ctx3d.useProgram(progObj);

    ctx3d.viewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    vertexBuff = ctx3d.createBuffer();
    ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuff);
    ctx3d.bufferData(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]), ctx3d.STATIC_DRAW);

    texBuff = ctx3d.createBuffer();
    ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuff);
    ctx3d.bufferData(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]), ctx3d.STATIC_DRAW);

    vloc = ctx3d.getAttribLocation(progObj, "aVertex"); 
    tloc = ctx3d.getAttribLocation(progObj, "aUV");
    uLoc = ctx3d.getUniformLocation(progObj, "pos");

    img = new Image();
    img.src = "image.jpg";

    img.onload = function(){
        tex = ctx3d.createTexture();
        ctx3d.bindTexture(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        ctx3d.texParameteri(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, ctx3d.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, ctx3d.NEAREST);
        ctx3d.texParameteri(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, ctx3d.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, ctx3d.NEAREST);
        ctx3d.texImage2D(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, 0,  ctx3d.RGBA,  ctx3d.RGBA, ctx3d.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this);

        ctx3d.enableVertexAttribArray(vloc);
        ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuff);
        ctx3d.vertexAttribPointer(vloc, 2, ctx3d.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        ctx3d.enableVertexAttribArray(tloc);
        ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuff);
        ctx3d.bindTexture(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        ctx3d.vertexAttribPointer(tloc, 2, ctx3d.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        ctx3d.drawArrays(ctx3d.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Andor! This is very cool. I am trying to do a simple thing but in a Worker as all my code is in a worker. I am trying to take two images, scale first to 64x64 and scale second to be 16x16 and overlap them, with second image on top and in the bottom right corner. I used your code here but it is drawing upside down - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzvkar

Comment: The reason I'm trying to force this is because I am making a firefox targeted app and need to do this simple work in a worker in Firefox. All my code is in worker and currently OffscreenCanvas only supports webgl.

Comment: @Noitidart It's missing a call to ctx3d.pixelStorei(ctx3d.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

Comment: @diegocr where should the function pixelStorei place?

Comment: @Andor also the image.jpg is any image? when i place my image.jpg, the output is a black output

Comment: @Jasonw after the call to bindTexture, and yes image.jpg can be any image supported by the browser, a black output just does mean there is something wrong at time of drawing i think, re-review your code.

Comment: ok, the image dimension has to be in 16x16 or else the output will be a black canvas.