# How can I draw and project a video from an HTML5 player onto a 3D plane in WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, webgl, http-live-streaming, unity-webgl

I'm using Unity to build my app to WebGL, and I've found myself needing to grab video from an HTML player and draw it on a plane in the 3D space.

I know you can call [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) on a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` and pass in a reference to the video player, and the current frame will be drawn to the canvas when the function's run.

The closest 3D equivalent I've been able to find for that function is [`WebGL2RenderingContext.texImage3D()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/texImage3D). However, I don't entirely understand how it works, and when I tried testing it, I received the following exception: `Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.` I used my own, local video file, so it can't be CORS, but I don't know what it is.

You can see the test project in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/dsaghliani/WebGL-video-test).

---

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250953/drawing-an-image-using-webgl), but unfortunately, the answers show how to draw what I assume are pre-loaded textures. I don't know how to grab those from the video player and pass them, or if that's fast enough to be done every frame.

---

To give some context, I'm trying to show an HLS live-stream inside my Unity/WebGL app. I could download the `.ts` (MPEG-2 Transport Stream) video segments and queue them up into a coherent video stream, but Unity's built-in video player doesn't support this format.

As a solution, I thought I might grab the video in an HTML5 player (using [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) if necessary) and inject the texture into the WebGL app, using JavaScript, every frame.

Unity lets you run JavaScript code from inside its C# scripts, so timing probably won't be an issue, nor getting the world scale/location of the target plane. I just need to write the JavaScript function to somehow draw the texture.

Here is [my current code](https://github.com/dsaghliani/WebGL-video-test/blob/main/index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebGL</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.10.1/dist/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video muted autoplay width="480" height="270">
        <source src="./test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <br>
    <canvas width="1080" height="720"></canvas>
    <button onclick="takeScreenshot()">Capture</button>
    
    <script>
        function takeScreenshot() {
            var video = document.querySelector("video");
            var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

            var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

            gl.texImage3D(
                gl.TEXTURE_3D,    // target (enum)
                0,                // level of detail
                gl.RGBA,          // internalFormat
                1920,             // width of texture
                1080,             // height of texture
                1,                // depth
                0,                // border
                gl.RGBA,          // format
                gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
                video,            // source
            );
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the test project code, since you put the html and video in same location you should set your _"source"_ as `src="test.mp4"` not as `src="./test.mp4"`. It worked for me and your code is fine (tested on Chrome).

Comment: @VC.One Weird. I changed it as you said, but it still doesn't work. Chrome gives a more verbose error message: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage3D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The video element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.` But it obviously doesn't! Edit: Hosting it on `localhost` fixed that issue. Still doesn't work, though: `(index):30 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: texImage3D: no texture bound to target` You didn't get this issue, either?

Comment: Yeah my bad. I was sleepy and remember changing the source. I think I saw the video tag   output & no GPU compiler's alert/pop-up & sleepily assumed _"No problem here, case solved"_. Sorry. I've made it up to you with a complete & testable example (edited from one of my projects)

Comment: PPS: Test code in localhost or use online MP4 link to avoid security issues when drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code to setup a webGL object (a Plane), that can receive your video's pixels.

Basically:

- Create a box/rectangle shape using two triangles...
- Then project the video pixels onto that rectangle (as a texture map).

  ```
    0-------1
    |       |
    3-------2

  //# two sets of... connected 3-points of a triangle
  var vertexIndices = [ 0,  2,  1,      0,  2,  3, ];
  ```

The example code below also creates some required GPU shaders and programs. 
Experiment with it

If any coders just want to do GPU pixel effects then write your effects code in the Fragment shader.
(see code part at: `//# example of basic colour effect`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebGL</title>
    
    <!--
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.10.1/dist/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>
    -->
    
    <style> body {background-color: aquamarine; } </style>  
</head>

<body>
    <video id="myVideo" controls muted autoplay width="480" height="270">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <br>
    
    <button id="capture" onclick="takeScreenshot()"> Capture </button>
    <br><br>
    
    <!--
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1080" height="720"></canvas>
    -->
    
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="270"></canvas>
    
<!-- ########## Shader code ###### -->
<!-- ### Shader code here -->


<!-- Fragment shader program -->
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

//<!-- //## code for pixel effects goes here if needed -->

//# these two vars will access 
varying mediump vec2 vDirection;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) 
{
    //# get current video pixel's color (no FOR-loops needed like in JS Canvas)
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vDirection.x * 0.5 + 0.5, vDirection.y * 0.5 + 0.5));
    
    /*
    //# example of basic colour effect
    gl_FragColor.r = ( gl_FragColor.r * 1.15 );
    gl_FragColor.g = ( gl_FragColor.g * 0.8 );
    gl_FragColor.b = ( gl_FragColor.b * 0.45 );
    */
}

</script>


<!-- Vertex shader program -->
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    attribute mediump vec2 aVertexPosition;
    varying mediump vec2 vDirection;

    void main( void ) 
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0, 1.0) * 2.0;
        vDirection = aVertexPosition;
    }
    


</script>



<!-- ### END Shader code... -->

    
<script>

//# WebGL setup

var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');

const glcanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const gl = ( ( glcanvas.getContext("webgl") ) || ( glcanvas.getContext("experimental-webgl") ) );

//# check if WebGL is available..
if (gl && gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext) { console.log( "WebGL is available"); }
else { console.log( "WebGL is NOT available" ); } //# use regular JS canvas functions if this happens...


//# create and attach the shader program to the webGL context
var attributes, uniforms, program;

function attachShader( params ) 
{
    fragmentShader = getShaderByName(params.fragmentShaderName);
    vertexShader = getShaderByName(params.vertexShaderName);

    program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) 
    { alert("Unable to initialize the shader program: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program)); }

    gl.useProgram(program);

    // get the location of attributes and uniforms
    attributes = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < params.attributes.length; i++) 
    {
        var attributeName = params.attributes[i];
        attributes[attributeName] = gl.getAttribLocation(program, attributeName);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes[attributeName]);
    }
        
    uniforms = {};

    for (i = 0; i < params.uniforms.length; i++) 
    {
        var uniformName = params.uniforms[i];
        uniforms[uniformName] = gl.getUniformLocation(program, uniformName);
        
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes[uniformName]);
    }
    
}

function getShaderByName( id ) 
{
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

    var theSource = "";
    var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

    while(currentChild) 
    {
        if (currentChild.nodeType === 3) { theSource += currentChild.textContent; }
        currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
    }

    var result;
    
    if (shaderScript.type === "x-shader/x-fragment") 
    { result = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER); } 
    else { result = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER); }
    
    gl.shaderSource(result, theSource);
    gl.compileShader(result);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(result, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) 
    {
        alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(result));
        return null;
    }
    return result;
}

//# attach shader
attachShader({
fragmentShaderName: 'shader-fs',
vertexShaderName: 'shader-vs',
attributes: ['aVertexPosition'],
uniforms: ['someVal', 'uSampler'],
});

// some webGL initialization
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gl.clearDepth(1.0);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

positionsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionsBuffer);
var positions = [
  -1.0, -1.0,
   1.0, -1.0,
   1.0,  1.0,
  -1.0,  1.0,
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vertexColors = [0xff00ff88,0xffffffff];
    
var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

verticesIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesIndexBuffer);

var vertexIndices = [ 0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3, ];

gl.bufferData(  
                gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                new Uint16Array(vertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW
            );

texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

//# must be LINEAR to avoid subtle pixelation (double-check this... test other options like NEAREST)
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

// update the texture from the video
updateTexture = function() 
{
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    
    //# next line fails in Safari if input video is NOT from same domain/server as this html code
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
};

</script>

<script>


//# Vars for video frame grabbing when system/browser provides a new frame
var requestAnimationFrame = (window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame);

var cancelAnimationFrame = (window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame);

///////////////////////////////////////////////


function takeScreenshot( ) 
{
    //# video is ready (can display pixels)
    if( video.readyState >= 3 )
    {
        updateTexture(); //# update pixels with current video frame's pixels...
        
        gl.useProgram(program); //# apply our program
    
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionsBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributes['aVertexPosition'], 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        
        //# Specify the texture to map onto the faces.
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.uniform1i(uniforms['uSampler'], 0);
        
        //# Draw GPU
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesIndexBuffer);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
    
    //# re-capture the next frame... basically the function loops itself
    //# consider adding event listener for video pause to set value as... cancelAnimationFrame( takeScreenshot ); 
    requestAnimationFrame( takeScreenshot ); 
    
}

//////////////////////////////////////

function takeScreenshot_old() 
{
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

    gl.texImage3D(
        gl.TEXTURE_3D,    // target (enum)
        0,                // level of detail
        gl.RGBA,          // internalFormat
        1920,             // width of texture
        1080,             // height of texture
        1,                // depth
        0,                // border
        gl.RGBA,          // format
        gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
        video,            // source
    );
}


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. A lot more than I expected. How would this translate to projecting into 3D space? I've been messing around with the `positions` variable — adding a third dimension — and adjusting the shader code accordingly, but all that did was draw 1 triangle instead of 2. Also, on line 130, did you perhaps mean to write `uniforms[uniformName]` instead of `attributes[uniformName]`?

Comment: Do you mean, for example, you want the video projected onto a cube? I've never tried that.  My project just used a 2D box because I was doing heavy pixel effects on a video (in Canvas it took 4 seconds per each frame, but on GPU it's smooth playback). See if [this tutorial link](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cube-maps.html) gives you some hints about texturing in 3D space. For a non-cube shape see [their other tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). PS: Explain _"projecting into 3D space"_ and I'll see what can be tried.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out. As I said, I have an existing WebGL app exported by Unity, the game engine. But Unity's video player doesn't support the kind of file type I need, so I thought I might use the browser's player to do that, grab the texture data, and pass it to the app somehow. I figured I might create a quad in the app, plastered on a wall, from within the JS code and stream the video texture to it. Or, maybe, if possible, I could maybe create an accessible field/variable in the app memory, if WebGL supports that, and write to it from the browser and read from the app/game.

Comment: "I figured I might create a quad in the app, plastered on a wall, from within the JS code and stream the video texture to it." Better explanation: imagine a TV mounted on the wall, in a 3D room. I need to play the video on that TV. The room already exists, as does the TV. But I need to use the browser's player to make sense of the data in the video file, and then somehow stream the texture, every frame of the video, to the display on the TV. Since the room is 3D, the display — the quad — needs to have a world-space location, scale, and orientation.